# Is it possible to create a blank page with 'pre-populated' code inside?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, populate

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet which can be clicked to open a new 'blank page' using `about:blank` or similar.

Here's the rub. The new blank page needs to have source code inside of it. specifically it needs to have javascript inside of it which waits for the new blank page to finish loading/instantiating (whichever is relevant), and then displays an alert box reading 'success!' or similar.

So far everything I have tried has caused the alert to be displayed in the *current* tab at the same time the new blank page is created in a different tab... or else it has cause the new blank page tab to instantiate only after the alert box has been displayed and addressed in the current tab.

Here is what I've tried.

```
javascript:
window.open('about:blank'); window.alert('success');

javascript:
var a = window.alert('success');
var b = window.open('about:blank', '', '_blank');
b.document.write(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  window.open('data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><script>alert("success");</script><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body>', 'myTab');
```

For some reason the above code does not work in Chrome. In this case you can use this:

```
var page = window.open();
page.document.open();
page.document.write('<html><div>Mert</div></html>');
page.document.close();
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Unfortunately when I tried adding a script tag into the mix so that I can get my alert box functioning properly, the bookmarklet fails to do anything.

Comment: what does happen? Can you give more details?

Comment: I would give more details if I could, but as far as I can tell, literally nothing happens. It's as if I had tried the following: `javascript:window.aler(3+4);`. Since in this example I misspelled `alert`, the bookmarklet will simply *not launch*. Here is my actual code, copied and pasted: `window.open('data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><script>window.alert('success!');</script></body>', 'myTab');`

Comment: you wanna show the alert in the newly opened page, right?

Comment: Yes, and my mistake --something does happen. The contents of the bookmarklet get displayed in the address bar, but still the browser fails to load a new tab, or even load the data page in the current tab.

Comment: You probably use Chrome?

Comment: I use Vivaldi, which I think operates on the same engine as chrome, but more closely related to opera? I dunno I'm not overly savvy on this under the hood stuff. At any rate your most recent answer update solved my problem :) Thanks so much